What does this mean in RISC-V opcode table
I want to check my understanding of how the imm[20|10:1|11|19:12] specifies the bit arrangements in the JAL (jump and link) instruction in RISC-V architecture?
I know the opcode takes up the lower 7-bits, the destination register then uses the next 5-bits, totaling 12 bits. The imm value is then encoded in the remaining higher 20-bits.
Are these remaining 20-bits located in this instruction as follows?
20-bits
<bit 20>, <bits 10 downto 1>, <bit 11>, <bits 19 downto 12> 



They are just 20 bits in the specified order:

From RISC-V User-Level ISA V2.2, p16

WTH is wrong with the distribution of the immediate bits? oO

@jusaca it's for quick parallel decode because most of the fields are in fixed position. In fact RISC-V probably has the simplest instruction decoder among the HPC architectures. Read the RISC-V spec, it's explained clearly there along with all the design rationale

I will look into the spec, this actually intrigues me. Without having read the spec yet I can't imagine how this layout of bits can be advantegous, but I believe you ;)

@phuclv could you comment with a link to a document explaining, I'll happily add to this answer.

@jusaca @jonathanjo please check RISC-V: Immediate Encoding Variants, Why are RISC-V S-B and U-J instruction types encoded in this way?, Why does RISC-V 'J-immediate' encode imm[11] in inst[20]?

@jusaca Having created a RISC-V instruction decoder on FPGA recently, it is fairly straightforward. Nothing other than swapping bit orders as the offset addresses are signed.
